# iframe shows when accessing on the local network but not outside

Tags: php, html, iframe

We had a "coder" setup a PHP page on our Voip phone system.  It is running Apache on a Centos 6.5 system.  There are 4 iframes that link to pages in the same machine.  When accessing the parent page locally (same network) the iframes work fine.  Accessing the parent page from a different network, the parent page loads fine but the iframes time out and fail.  Here is a sample of the iframe code:

```
<table id="summary">
    <tr><td colspan="1"><h5>Summary Report</h5><hr></td></tr>
    <tr>
    <td><width = "300px"><iframe align="center" width="800px" height="300px" src="http://<?php echo "$ipaddressNimbus"?>/Reports/SummaryReport.php" frameborder=yes scrolling="yes" name="myIframe" id="myIframe"> </iframe></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <br><br>
```

Can someone comment as to why this won't work?  The initial system is Freepbx and every othe rpage works fine.

Thanks

Comment: Do the URLs of the inner and outer frames match?

Comment: If you're using Chrome, press `CTRL+SHIFT+J` to open the dev console and look for errors. It's probably a problem with the "Same Origin policy" (iframes have to be on the same domain as the parent site.